# Partial Differential Equations Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given the differential equation

$
A_{1}U_{xx}+A_{2}U_{yy}+A_{3}U_{xy}+A_{4}U_{x}+A_{5}U_{y}=U
$

what does the value of $(A_{3})^{2}-A_{2}A_{1}$ mean whether its equal, less or larger than zero?
I remember reading that this equation determines something about the PDE.

Comment: look at the [classification section on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation).